zig programs on solana
I'm trying to deploy a solana zig program, but running into some ELF issues and was wondering if someone has any experience with that
here is my repo for reproduction https://github.com/anticode-dev/zigsol/tree/master
thank you

Feel free to reach out on GitHub over an issue if you're still having problems! At https://github.com/joncinque/solana-program-sdk-zig or https://github.com/joncinque/solana-zig-bootstrap

Here you can find a working zig program example:
https://github.com/joncinque/solana-program-rosetta/tree/main/transfer-lamports/zig
with instructions on how to run it.

thanks so much! very helpful
